# Android rename SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is it possible to rename a database already created in android?

On my apps update I would like to rename the old database and install a new then compare some values and finally delete the old.

I am doing the creation from an sqlite file in the assets folder. This is why I cannot rename all the tables and insert the new ones.

Clarification:

The old database will contain only one table that I need to compare values from against the new (from the update) database.

Both databases have been copied over from an sqlite file in the assets folder.

Once I have compared a values from the old database to new I will delete the old and use the new in its place with the values I compared.

What i was thinking of doing was rename the old create the new in its place and do everything above.

Comment: Why are you doing that much of stuff what about if direct update the database at time of app update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lord Flash is right, you should delete the old db and copy the new one…

Assuming you use a `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you could use a `createDatabaseIfRequired();` method in `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWritableDatabase()`

```
private boolean checkOldDatabase() {
    Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, "OperationDbHelper.checkDatabase");
    File f = new File(DB_PATH + OLD_DB_NAME);
    return f.exists();
}

public void createDatabaseIfRequired() throws IOException, SQLiteException {
    if (!checkOldDatabase()) {
      // do db comparison / delete old db / copy new db
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just rename the File.  Make sure the database is closed first!

Call this in your activity class:

```
private void renameDatabase()
{
    File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("yourdb.whatever");
    File oldDatabaseFile = new File(databaseFile.getParentFile(), "yourdb_old.whatever");

    databaseFile.renameTo(oldDatabaseFile);
}
```

Response to clarification.  Rename the old db (as above), copy the new one from the assets folder, open both databases and do your compare.  Then delete the old file.

Comment: why would I rename the file? I am writing the database from the file. Once written it is never used again.

Comment: From your question: "Is it possible to rename a database already created in android?"  That means renaming the file, essentially. What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Again, "... I would like to rename the old database and install a new ...".  Still confused.  That's renaming a file.  Are you trying to copy a new TABLE?  Different question.

Comment: While this doesn't exactly match the question, it perfectly answers what I was looking for.  +1, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to rename a sql table directly.

But you may copy it creating a new and deleting the old one.

Comment: Ah that sounds perfect could you possibly provide a simple sample or link to something useful. The only other thing I need to get my head around is how I will be connecting to two databases at once to do some comparisions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kevin Galligan's answer, I was able to create a function in my Kotlin Android app that I can use whenever it might ever be necessary, to rename the database files.

If you're using Java, you'll need to change the syntax a bit but the code should hopefully be somewhat self-explanatory.

```
val x: String = "Hello"
//in Kotlin would be
String x = "Hello";
//in Java, for example.
```

Anyway, here's my code, feel free to ask questions if you have any:

```
private fun checkAndRenameDatabase(oldName: String, newName: String) {
    val oldDatabaseFile: File = getDatabasePath(oldName)
    val oldDatabaseJournal: File = getDatabasePath("${oldName}-journal")

    // Can use this to check files beforehand, using breakpoints 
    //val files = oldDatabaseFile.parentFile.listFiles()

    if(oldDatabaseFile.exists() || oldDatabaseJournal.exists()) {
        db.close()  // Ensure existing database is closed

        val newDatabaseFile: File = getDatabasePath(newName)
        val newDatabaseJournal: File = getDatabasePath("${newName}-journal")

        if(oldDatabaseFile.exists()) {
            if(newDatabaseFile.exists()) {
                newDatabaseFile.delete()
            }
            oldDatabaseFile.renameTo(newDatabaseFile)
        }

        if(oldDatabaseJournal.exists()) {
            if(newDatabaseJournal.exists()) {
                newDatabaseJournal.delete()
            }
            oldDatabaseJournal.renameTo(newDatabaseJournal)
        }

        // Use with breakpoints to ensure files are now in order
        //val newFiles = oldDatabaseFile.parentFile.listFiles()

        // Re-open database with new name
        db = SQLiteDBHelper(applicationContext, newName)
    }
}
```