# Can't edit SQLite database name

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I can't edit my database name and I can't find the list of information I put into the database.

If I try to change the database name from "diet" to something else, I'm still able to run but there's the green underline typo. I'm following this tutorial.

```
public class DietDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_WEIGHT = "weight";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER," +
                    COLUMN_NAME_WEIGHT + " INTEGER )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "diet";

    public DietDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot a link to the tutorial. What is "the green underline typo"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android rename SQLite Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203941/android-rename-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

I would change your database name code from
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "diet";

to 
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "diet.db";
All of my sqlite column names, table and database names are highlighted in green.

Answer (score -1):

you have to change database version for each change that you make in your database structure. for example change :

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

to

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
```

and so on for every change.
I hope it will help

Comment: Changing the file name results in a completely new file.